# How to make UI set active when you press tab but if its still active press tab again and the UI will be set Inactive in unity 2d c#

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2d right now and I'm making some inventory Ui but I cant seem to figure out how to open and close UI with one key. like in most games when you press escape and it opens a pause screen then if you press it again then it closes it. I'm not sure how I can get what I'm looking for. but I tried it and here is what I have

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) {
            GameMenu.SetActive(true);
            if(GameMenu.activeSelf && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) {
                GameMenu.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a bool variable to store the state of UI, like:

```
private bool isMenuActive = false;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
{
        if (isMenuActive)
        {
            GameMenu.SetActive(false);
            isMenuActive = false;   
        }
        else
        {
            GameMenu.SetActive(true);
            isMenuActive = true;
        }
 }
```

Or more consice:

```
private bool isMenuActive = false;

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) 
{
        isMenuActive = !isMenuActive;
        GameMenu.SetActive(isMenuActive); 
}
```

Or more consice:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) 
{
    GameMenu.SetActive(!GameMenu.activeSelf);
}
```

Comment: hmmm. that's a great idea but still doesn't work. with the if (isMenuActive)
        {
            GameMenu.SetActive(flase);
            isMenuActive = false;   
        }
you are just going straight to turning off the menu if the menu is active. or do I have to set the bool after all of that if i want the menu to turn off?

Comment: There was a typo (flase (x) => false (o)), so it didn't work.

Comment: no it was not the typo. I saw that and fixed it. I think it's something else. maybe that your not setting the bool true anywhere?

Comment: I've tested it. There is a one-line solution : `GameMenu.SetActive(!GameMenu.activeSelf).`

Comment: that's a little confusing. wdym by " There is a one-line solution" like where would I put that? and could you tell me what it does?

Comment: Which game object do you assign the scirpt to? If you assign the script to the menu object itself, it doesn't work since when it is disabled, you can not call its script's monobehaviour method (i.e., Update). So you need to put the script to another game object.

Comment: it is on my canvas object. and it never gets disabled.

Comment: My test script:
`using UnityEngine;

public class CavasTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject OBYouWantToControl;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
  {
            OBYouWantToControl.SetActive(!OBYouWantToControl.activeSelf);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You need to assign the menu object to the OBYouWantToControl from inspector.

Comment: oh hey what do you know your one line solution worked. thank you vary much for the help.